# How to make Delphi OLEContainer display Acrobat PDF files inline instead of starting Acrobat Reader instance?

Tags: delphi, ole

My Delphi app has a generic viewer to view DOC/DOCX, XLS/XLSX and PDF files using a TOleContainer. Users will have MS-Office and Acrobat Reader installed on their PCs.

This is implemented by using simply a TOleContainer control. The TOleContainer is placed in a TForm with Align=alClient.

The problem: The OLEContainer is opening the documents inline in the control for MS-Office documents (DOC/DOCX/XLS/XLSX). This is the desired behavior. However for PDF files, it displays a preview of the PDF document - first page only without scrollbars in the control - and it additionally opens a separate Acrobat Reader window and loads the document in that. I want the user experience to be consistent and avoid having it open a separate Acrobat Reader window to view the PDF document.

Is there any 'trick' to get it to work as desired?

This is the current code:

```
object OleContainer1: TOleContainer
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Width = 533
  Height = 592
  AutoActivate = aaGetFocus
  Align = alClient
  BorderStyle = bsNone
  Caption = 'OleContainer1'
  SizeMode = smAutoSize
  TabOrder = 0
  ExplicitLeft = 1
  ExplicitTop = 1
  ExplicitWidth = 427
  ExplicitHeight = 433
end

procedure TfmDocPrv.PreviewDocument(const ADocumentFile: String);
begin
  Screen.Cursor := crHourGlass;
  OleContainer1.CreateObjectFromFile(ADocumentFile, False);
  Screen.Cursor := crArrow;
end;
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you have to live with that if you use reader. What you need is a proper pdf viewer control.

Comment: You only have this behaviour if you set the container to aaGetFocus, try it...

Comment: @whosrdaddy: Yes. Changed to "aaManual" and its better now ie. not opening a Acrobat window. But its still a read-only control showing only the 1st page without a scroll bar. I guess I need to do as Heffernan recommended and use a PDF viewer control. I've done that before with Acrobat OCX or TLB..

Comment: I want the opposite. PDFs, BMPs, ZIPs are opened in a separate window as i need. But I want MsWord do the same. Changing autoactivate does nothing. Is there a solution, please ?